# Regexing a multiline pattern in bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I want to grab a multiline pattern with bash

I have a method using `cmd | tee >(grep 552) | grep 210` that works but it spits out all the 552's, then all the 210's. It would be a lot easier to read if it spit out pairs of 552's with the corresponding 210's.

This is how I would do it in python, but I've yet to figure out how to do it in bash. May be some awk/grep command?

Python example:

```
(552)(.*)(.|\n|\r)*?(210)(.*)
```

Or with noncaptures specified, would be:

```
(?:552)(.*)(?:.|\n|\r)*?(?:210)(.*)
```

Sample input:

```
properties 552 I want
220 a logg don't want this
props 210 These
...
552 And these
...
ex 210 too
```

Sample output:

```
I want
These

And these
too
```

Also okay:

```
properties 552 I want
props 210 These

552 And these
ex 210 too
```

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1).  There are many people here who will downvote on this issue.

Comment: regex varies a lot from tool to tool... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y ... `grep -P` and `perl` would be closest option for given regex

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, you can use `sed` with an alternation:

```
sed -nE 's/^.*(552|210) *//p' file
```

```
I want
These
And these
too
```

If this is not what you're looking for then I suggest you post a different sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this sample input file:

```
$ cat file
552 Start1
123 other
210 End1
123 other
123 other
552 Start2
210 End2
```

#### Using awk

```
$ awk '/552/,/210/' file
552 Start1
123 other
210 End1
552 Start2
210 End2
```

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -n '/552/,/210/p' file
552 Start1
123 other
210 End1
552 Start2
210 End2
```

#### Using GNU grep

```
$ grep -ozP '552(.|\n|\r)*?210[^\n]*\n' file
552 Start1
123 other
210 End1
552 Start2
210 End2
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need the lines between the start and end patterns

```
$ awk '/^552\y/ && ORS=OFS;  
       /^210\y/ && ORS=RS' file
```

will give (using @John1024's input file)

```
552 Start1 210 End1
552 Start2 210 End2
```

or, if you want them on separate lines

```
$ awk '/^552\y/ || /^210\y/'

552 Start1
210 End1
552 Start2
210 End2
```

if you're looking for an exact literal match on field one, perhaps writing `$1=="552" || $1=="210"` is better.